# High voltage high power low side mosfet switch - anti spark circuit

Tags: mosfet, switches

I have made an Aniti spark circuit based on https://github.com/msglazer/Anti-Spark_Switch
My version however is made to work with up to 200V and hefty current at that (4x IRF200P222):

[image]

Circuit does work but it has one flaw I somehow missed when designing/copying it. Switch works in reverse.

I have spent some time in LTSpice trying to figure out safe way to reverse that but I am not sure about my solutions so my question is:

How to make it turn on when leads 3 and 4 on J3 connector is shorted?

Problems to overcome:

1. Huge input voltage range 24-200V
2. Initial power spike on mosfet when turning on
3. Making sure it doesn't sap too much power from battery when turned off.

EDIT:

A little clarification

1. Everything can be changed except for mosfets
2. There is no need to change core of schematic, might as well do sub circuit, I was briefly thinking about simple relay to transform SPST to SPDT.
3. Whole problem with current switch is safety, I do not like that by accidentally cutting switch wires, whole device turns on.

EDIT2:

I do not want to change Switch itself because it is ignition switch and also because of safety concerns. So pretty much any method that can achieve this is acceptable.

In case of cutting switch wires, circuit has to turn off.

Comment: This design relies upon the default state being "on" when power is applied. This makes sense because there wouldn't be a spark to suppress if the default state were "off". You seem to be suggesting that you want to apply power, with the default state being "off", and then to press the button to switch "on". Is that correct?

Comment: What are we free to change? Because simply as it is, shorting 3 and 4 will unconditionally turn the circuit off. Perhaps the behavior you're after only involves using a NO switch (like the original circuit) instead of NC (like you did in your circuit)?

Comment: @SimonFitch i did clarify in EDIT what I am after. Especially point 3.